# How to design a personal messaging database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I wish to make a PM (personal messaging) system but have been struggling in setting up a fluid database that links the users of my 'user' table with the messages table.

In my PM system if you were to go to the interface, you will see the avatar of the sender, the name of the sender, and the message of the sender. The database however will have the names of the sender and recipient, the content of the message along with the timestamp the message(s) was sent. The database will also keep track if a message has been removed from a user's(s') inbox.

Here is what I've done: Three tables have been setup ('users' table, 'messages' table). The 'users' table contains all registered users with a primary auto_incremented id. The 'messages' table contains a primary auto_incremented message_id, a row that contains user_id, a row with the TIMESTAMP the message(s) was(were) sent, and a row with message_content. Is my setup correct in fulfilling what I want?

The issue I am having is that the messages of the sender are not linking with the intended recipient (in fact, I don't even know where the messages are even going).

Comment: Your prose is pretty good, but how about sharing your actual table schemas or a simplified version of it, as opposed to writing it out. To debug your problem we'll also likely need to see your `INSERT` statements. The one thing your `messages` table is at least missing is that it needs a reference to two user ids: the sender and recipient. So `sender_user_id` and `recipient_user_id` instead of just `user_id`.

Comment: @Evert Thank you very much! Huh, that makes a lot of sense. So then if I need to reference to two user ids ( I can handle one user but I struggle with coding for two) can I just make two separate variables sender & recipient but link them both to user_id? I don't know; how would I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're trying to write a database schema you have to think of tables like you would entities (*things*). The table's job is to describe a single thing or some part of a thing. That description is made up of attributes (*columns*). Each row can only describe one thing or one part of a thing (meaning multiple tables can represent individual parts of one thing). This is called [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

So in your case you have 3 primary things you are concerned with.

1. A User
2. A Message
3. An Inbox

If you think about the relationships described between these three things you can conclude that your schema is basically just the framework for a set of answers to question you know you will ask later.

For example, if every user must have an inbox and every inbox may have messages then the `Inbox` schema needs to have a `user_id` column that allows you to identify which inbox belongs to which user. Additionally, since an inbox may have one or more messages then it must also contain an `inbox_id` (this would be your auto increment id) which would allow you to identify a unique inbox in the table. Obviously the `Message` schema also needs a `message_id` column to uniquely identify each message. The schema also needs a `user_id` column that identifies which user the message belongs to (i.e. the author of the message).

However, since there is a one-to-many relationship between `Inbox` and `Message` and a many-to-many relationship between `User` and `Message` then you can't describe the relationship between them in the same table easily without creating logical inconsistencies. This is called [3NF or Third Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).

So instead you create a fourth table that simply describes the relationship between an inbox and its messages. Let's call this the `Recipient` table for now.

The `Recipient` table needs to know about the inbox as well as the message and which user in the user table is the recipient of this message. That means you need 3 PKs or Primary Keys here.

1. `inbox_id`
2. `message_id`
3. `user_id` // this will be the id of the recipient

Remember, number 3 on that list is the id of the user that the message was sent to, not the user that wrote the message (that is already identified by the `Message` table).

Now when you want to know which messages are in a given user's inbox you simply query the `Recipient` and join it on `User` and `Message` like so...

```
SELECT mesage.user_id AS Sender, message.contents, recipient.user_id AS Recipient
FROM recipient, inbox
JOIN message ON recipient.message_id = message.id
WHERE inbox.user_id = ?
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Not only was I able to fully comprehend your explanation, I got really excited at how elegant, simple, and ordered your logic was in presenting this. I will try this out immediately and will check back in to report.

Comment: Huh, this may actually take a while to network the php with the database. A question though: since I already have a unique primary auto increment key in my users table I will not need to the the user_id in the other tables as primary keys, right or is every attribute a PK? Phpadmin seems to be only allowing one PK per table. Thank you!

Comment: No, you can't have more than one primary key per row, but you certainly _could_ have multiple prime attributes that make up a primary key (this is called a composite key). In your case you aren't making the `user_id` a PK in another table, you are merely indexing it to other tables.

Comment: I see, so let me get this straight and you can whack me across the head if I am wrong: users table has user_id as PK, inbox table has user_id (as an INT) but with inbox_id as the PK but 2 indexes for user_id and inbox_id, in the messages table message_id is the PK with user_id as an INT but the table has two indexes for the two id's, and recipient table will just have three indexes for the inbox_id, user_id, and message_id, correct? Thank you, and forgive me if I am irritating you for sounding like a turnip.